# Django Admin Page Links Broken

Tags: python, django, url, localhost, admin

I am running Django on Apache (on localhost). The admin page works fine, my issue is with every link on this page. Since a shareroom hosted on our servers uses `/admin/`, in order to reach my Django admin page i had to change the following in `urls.py` :

```
 urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'/admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
   )
```

TO

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'/control/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

However, now when I click on any link on the page (such as `Groups` under `Auth`), it brings me to `control/auth/group/` in the browser, instead of `http://localhost/django_ngs/control/auth/group/` . I must be missing a connection to admin after I changed the url. I have to append the project part of the url but am not sure how. Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

**Edit**: Basically it is NOT appending the destination to the current link. The links point to `control/auth/group/` instead of `http://localhost/django_ngs/control/auth/group/` or `/control/auth/group/`

**Edit 2:** I can only reach my admin page using the `r'/control/'` format (with a slash in front), whereas it SHOULD be `r'^control/'`, with a carrot in front. This could be related to my issue (thanks knbk) Any ideas?

**Edit 3:** This is my entire `urls.py`

```
 from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
 from django.contrib import admin
 # Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
 from django.contrib import admin
 admin.autodiscover()

 urlpatterns = patterns('',
     url(r'/control/', include(admin.site.urls)),
 )
```

When I go to the admin page using the carrot, I get this:

[image]

Comment: Don't know if it's related to your issue, but your url patterns shouldn't start with a slash, it should be `r'^control/'`.

Comment: @knbk Interesting you bring that up... When I change it to that, I cannot reach the admin page. It gives me a 404. It will only work with the preceding forward slash instead of the carrot. Any ideas? That may VERY WELL be my problem...

Comment: Is this url config included from another config? If so, can you post your complete urlpatterns?

Comment: @knbk I just edited, posted my entire file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in the `django_ngs/` prefix to your urls. Django doesn't know about it, and all url patterns are root-relative.

Now, the string `django_ngs/control/` matches the regex `r'/control/'`. If you include a carot in the regex (`r'^control/'`), you require the string to start with the supplied pattern. This is generally what you want. E.g. if you later on add another app with all urls under `/something/`, and you need to add a page in that app named `/something/control/`, the url would still only match the first root-level page, not the second page in `/something/`.

The reason your links get broken, is because Django reverses the url pattern back to an url, but the pattern doesn't describe the `django_ngs/` prefix in any way. So, it gets left out in the generated url.

There are two solutions here. Either you prefix each pattern with `django_ngs/`, i.e:

```
url(r'^django_ngs/control/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

Or you can move the complete url configuration to another file, and include it in your main url config under `django_ngs/`:

```
url(r'^django_ngs/', include(myproject.other.file)),
```

Comment: Great find. Thank you very much! This was puzzling me for hours. Thanks so much.